# Adding a shell script to be executed with the 'mrt/meteor create' command in terminal

Tags: shell, terminal, meteor

How can I run a shell script that is executed when I enter the 'mrt create' command in the terminal?

Comment: i want to know this so bad. why people vote down?

Comment: Probably because I was verbose and unclear. My bad--was in a caffeinated stream of conscious. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question Johann!

Alright, so to turn a shell script into something as convenient as a terminal command, all you need to do is create an **alias** for that script in your terminal's rc file. Further instructions as to how you can do that can be found [here](http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_creating_aliases_commands).

So all you need to do is list out the commands you want automated in the shell script, including the meteor/mrt commands, and pass the directory/project name with the special variable "$1" passes the first argument after your command into your script.

[Here's the script I am currently using, which implements the folder structure from Discover Meteor and adds coffeescript and stylus-mixins](https://gist.github.com/jobez/5954802) There are probably some redundancies in commands. Let me know if you see anything that can be cleaned!